# Table Header HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create this table header in HTML. But I cant use the properly col-span limits.

Any help?

** I was able to get the solution, looks like its what I was looking for.

This website http://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/ helped.

[image]

My solution:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-s6z2{text-align:center}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="4">A</th>
    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="4">B</th>
    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="4">C</th>
    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="4">D</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh" colspan="8">E</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e" rowspan="3">F</td>
    <td class="tg-s6z2" colspan="7">G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-s6z2" colspan="6">H</td>
    <td class="tg-031e" rowspan="2">I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">J</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">K</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">L</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">M</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">N</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">O</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This solved my problem.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You provided a statement with a vague question. People can help but you have to be explicit with what your issue is and provide code of what you have tried already so that we can see where the issue is as Steve pointed out.

Comment: Your cols span multiple cols rows you have to use col and row spans. That's like saying I want a row but I can't use a tr :) You can always do absolutely positioned divs and manage the resizing... (just kidding, don't do it)